# How to add mustache Variable only if more than one condition is true

Tags: mustache

I have a mustache template like this.

```
{{#alpha}}{{alpha}}{{/alpha}} 
{{#beta}}{{beta}}{{/beta}}

\n{{gamma}}
```

The problem is the new line here (\n) **\n{{gamma}}** I want only to add it when at at least  alpha or beta or both are there. If alpha and beta are not there, I dont need the \n.

Prototype

```
if(alpha | beta){
 \n{{gamma}}
}else{
 {{gamma}}
 }
```

How I can solve it with a mustache template ?

Answer (score 0):

Mustace is supposed to be logic-free. You need to have a function elsewhere in your code that will set gamma = true based on the logic you describe.

Once gamma is set as true or false, you can then use the following:

```
{{#gamma}}
The text you want to appear when gamma is true
{{/gamma}}

{{^gamma}}
The text you want to appear when gamma is false
{{/gamma}}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The `gamma` variable is already given and might not be a boolean. The asker wants the insertion of a newline to depend on the `alpha` and `beta` variables.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Mustache specification](https://github.com/mustache/spec), section tags and their corresponding close tags are "standalone", which means that if they appear alone on a line, they leave no trace, not even an empty line. You can use this to control whitespace. At least in theory, because many Mustache implementations do not abide by the whitespace parts of the specification.

From your question, it is ambiguous whether you always want newlines to appear after the `alpha`, `beta` and empty lines and you want to control whether to have a fourth one before the `{{gamma}}`, or you just don't want to introduce empty lines for `alpha` and `beta` if they are empty. In the latter case, it is just a matter of placing the section tags and close section tags on separate lines:

```
{{#alpha}}
{{alpha}}
{{/alpha}} 
{{#beta}}
{{beta}}
{{/beta}}
{{gamma}}
```

In the former case, it takes a bit more juggling with sections and negative sections, but you can still do it:

```
{{#alpha}}{{alpha}}{{/alpha}}
{{#beta}}{{beta}}{{/beta}}

{{#alpha}}

{{/alpha}}
{{^alpha}}
{{#beta}}

{{/beta}}
{{/alpha}}
{{gamma}}
```

In the above template, if you need this conditional newline in many places, you can abstract away the section juggling into a separate template and use it as a partial, which is also standalone:

```
{{!abstracted-conditional-newline}}
{{#alpha}}

{{/alpha}}
{{^alpha}}
{{#beta}}

{{/beta}}
{{/alpha}}
```

```
{{#alpha}}{{alpha}}{{/alpha}}
{{#beta}}{{beta}}{{/beta}}

{{>abstracted-conditional-newline}}
{{gamma}}
```

You can try these templates in the [Wontache playground](https://jgonggrijp.gitlab.io/wontache/playground.html), which strictly follows the specification, by pasting the following code into its load/store box:

```
{"data":{"text":"{\n    alpha: '',\n    beta: '',\n    gamma: 'gamma',\n}"},"templates":[{"name":"original","text":"{{#alpha}}{{alpha}}{{/alpha}}\n{{#beta}}{{beta}}{{/beta}}\n\n{{gamma}}"},{"name":"single-newline","text":"{{#alpha}}\n{{alpha}}\n{{/alpha}} \n{{#beta}}\n{{beta}}\n{{/beta}}\n{{gamma}}"},{"name":"conditional-extra-newline","text":"{{#alpha}}{{alpha}}{{/alpha}}\n{{#beta}}{{beta}}{{/beta}}\n\n{{#alpha}}\n\n{{/alpha}}\n{{^alpha}}\n{{#beta}}\n\n{{/beta}}\n{{/alpha}}\n{{gamma}}"},{"name":"abstracted-conditional-newline","text":"{{#alpha}}\n\n{{/alpha}}\n{{^alpha}}\n{{#beta}}\n\n{{/beta}}\n{{/alpha}}\n"},{"name":"conditional-extra-newline-with-partial","text":"{{#alpha}}{{alpha}}{{/alpha}}\n{{#beta}}{{beta}}{{/beta}}\n\n{{>abstracted-conditional-newline}}\n{{gamma}}"}]}
```